# NoMethodError while MyMethod do exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I can't understand how can I solve this error since the method do really exists, I have tested  it with the 'Hi' method.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'tm'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Tm.hi
Hey Tm here for duty!
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> hashfile = YAML.load_file('fr.yaml')
=> {"fr"=>{"colors"=>{"yellow"=>"Jaune", "white"=>"Blanc"}, "hello"=>"Bonjour"}}
irb(main):005:0> t = load_translation(hashfile)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /Users/abderrahmane/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):5 NoMethodError (undefined method `load_translation' for main:Object)
```

With my class:

```
class Tm

  def self.hi
    puts "Hey Tm here for duty!"
  end

  def auxload(hash, lang, concat='')
    ans = {}
    hash.each do |key, val|
      if val.class == Hash
        aux = auxload(val, lang, concat+key+'.')
        aux.each do |k, v|
          ans[k]=v
        end
      else
        ans[concat+key]={lang => val}
      end
    end
    return ans
  end

  # load the translation from the yaml files
  def load_translation(hash)
    key,value = hash.first
    return auxload(value,key)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the method on your class you first need to create an instance of the class and then call the method on that instance. e.g.

```
tm = Tm.new
t = tm.load_translation(hashfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the `load_translation` method from the object of `class` `Tm`.

You need an instance of the class:

```
tm = Tm.new
tm.load_translation(hashfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to call the **load_translation** method at first by creating an instance of the class ~

```
tm = Tm.new
tm.load_translation(hashfile)
```